# How to use pandas rows to form new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following:

```
pa = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.array([[1.,4.],[2.],[3.,4.,5.]]), 
                   'b':np.array([[2.,5.],[3., 6.],[4.,5.,6.]])})
```

This will yield:

```
    a               b
0   [1.0, 4.0]      [2.0, 5.0]
1   [2.0, 3.3]      [3.0, 6.0]
2   [3.0, 4.0, 5.0] [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

I have tried various techniques to concatenate items of each array into a new array.

Something in this fashion:

```
    a               b               c
0   [1.0, 4.0]      [2.0, 5.0]      [1.0, 2.0]
1   [1.0, 4.0]      [2.0, 5.0]      [4.0, 5.0]
2   [2.0, 3.3]      [3.0, 6.0]      [2.0, 3.0]
3   [2.0, 3.3]      [3.0, 6.0]      [3.3, 6.0]
4   [3.0, 4.0, 5.0] [4.0, 5.0, 6.0] [3.0, 4.0]
5   [3.0, 4.0, 5.0] [4.0, 5.0, 6.0] [4.0, 5.0]
6   [3.0, 4.0, 5.0] [4.0, 5.0, 6.0] [5.0, 6.0]
```

if there are other columns I can update those items into the newly created columns. But I'm stuck in getting to this position.

Can anyone please help out?

Comment: I'm very confused and have no idea how your output is generated.

Comment: I'd like to know if what I am asking is even possible. I'm new to pandas and would like to know if it's even possible. Basically I would like a new array to be formed using the index in the arrays present in the rows of the pandas tables.

Comment: We can’t tell you if “it” is possible if we don’t know what “it” is.  You need to do a better job explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: @piRSquared I am trying to create a new array in a new column using the row items as shown. The new array would contain the index based items from the other row-items. taking row0 as eg, if a:[1,4] and b:[2,5] then i need to build c: a[1,2] and c:[4,5] . This is the 'it' I am referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `zip` with unnesting method

```
pa['New']=[list(zip(x,y)) for x, y in zip(pa.a,pa.b)]
s=pa.New.str.len()
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':pa['a'].repeat(s),'b':pa['b'].repeat(s),'New':list(map(list,pa.New.sum()))})
df
          New                a                b
0  [1.0, 2.0]       [1.0, 4.0]       [2.0, 5.0]
0  [4.0, 5.0]       [1.0, 4.0]       [2.0, 5.0]
1  [2.0, 3.0]       [2.0, 3.3]       [3.0, 6.0]
1  [3.3, 6.0]       [2.0, 3.3]       [3.0, 6.0]
2  [3.0, 4.0]  [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]  [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
2  [4.0, 5.0]  [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]  [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
2  [5.0, 6.0]  [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]  [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need something like this?

```
def f(row):
    return pd.Series(zip(row["a"], row["b"]))

mod = df.apply(f, 1).stack()
mod.index = mod.index.get_level_values(0)

df.merge(mod.to_frame(), left_index=True, right_index=True)

    a               b            c
0   [1.0, 4.0]  [2.0, 5.0]  (1.0, 2.0)
0   [1.0, 4.0]  [2.0, 5.0]  (4.0, 5.0)
1   [2.0, 3.3]  [3.0, 6.0]  (2.0, 3.0)
1   [2.0, 3.3]  [3.0, 6.0]  (3.3, 6.0)
2   [3.0, 4.0, 5.0] [4.0, 5.0, 6.0] (3.0, 4.0)
2   [3.0, 4.0, 5.0] [4.0, 5.0, 6.0] (4.0, 5.0)
2   [3.0, 4.0, 5.0] [4.0, 5.0, 6.0] (5.0, 6.0)
```